# Node.js ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED

Tags: node.js, solana, nft, candy-machine

I'm trying to create mintable NFT and while I was using metaplex sugar i see only one thing when using command "yarn start":

```
opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
```

This is how "scripts" look like:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start",,
    "lint": "prettier -c 'src/**/*.{ts,tsx}' && npm run lint:eslint",
    "lint:eslint": "eslint 'src/**/*.{ts,tsx}'",
    "lint:fix": "prettier --write 'src/**/*.{ts,tsx}' && eslint --fix 'src/**/*.{ts,tsx}'",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "craco eject"
  },
```

I tried using different versions of Nodes but nothing helped me. I tried to replace "scripts" using thhis:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "export SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && react-scripts start",
    "build": "export SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && react-scripts build"
}
```

but it still doesn't work.